# Continuous aspect for incomplete action

Tags: present-continuous

1. I’m washing a mop to clean my room.

In this situation, can I say I’m cleaning my room?

2. I turned off the light and I’m keeping it off.

In this situation, can I say I’m turning off the light?

Comment: If you're only preparing the mop, it sounds as though you haven't even started cleaning yet!

Comment: @Kate Bunting Could you please answer my second example? Thank you.

Comment: If you have already turned/switched off the light, obviously you are not still in the act of turning it off. The continuous tense is only used when the action described by the verb is ongoing.

Comment: @Kate Bunting That’s interesting. In Korean, you can use “버튼 누르고 있어” “불 키고 있어”

Comment: I don't read Korean, so you will have to translate.

Comment: @Kate Bunting 나는 버튼 누르고 있다. = I’m pressing the button (literal) = I pressed the button and I’m holding it (real meaning)

Comment: Surely a light switch doesn't normally have to be held down to stay in the 'off' position? If you are operating a switch that requires a button to be held (usually for the power to stay _on_, in my experience), you can certainly say "I'm pressing/holding the button".